# Objects moving when I drag them

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Im no pro with Illustrator, but I can work my way through it pretty well. I was working on some type today, and every time I click on an object to place it somewhere,when I get to my destination, the object is shaky. I have to move it back and forth a few times to get it  in place. I'll place it where it should be, and it moves just a tiny bit. Not accurately I guess I'm trying to say. It just started happening in the last few weeks and is driving me nuts. Any ideas?

Comment: Possibly aligning to pixel grid?

Comment: Could be a slow computer lagging so that the object is released with a slight delay.

Answer (score 2):

Could be grid snap, or pixel grid alignment. You can try turn off both options.

For grid snap go to **View** menu and uncheck **Snap to Grid**.

For pixel grid open the **Transform panel**, select the object and uncheck **Align to pixel grid**.